# Looking out for personalize folder which can be shared inside

Tags: personalization

I have requirement of creating a personal folder which needs to be created in SDL web 8 content manager and the user can share the same with another user if required. Please suggest if anybody have worked on such request.

Thanks 
Tapan Vaidya

Answer (score 3):

You can implement that requirement to some extent using CM security: create Folders for each User and ensure that initially only that User has Read and Write Permissions on the Folder.

In order to let the User share the Folder with others, he should be able to change his Folder's Access Control List. However, this means he would need to have Permission Management Right on the Publication and that gives him the right to change any ACL, not only his own Folder's.

You could create a UI extension which lets Users change their personal Folder's ACL only (using *elevated privileges*).